# Table join with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble to give the condition for tables' joining. The highlight parts are the 3 conditions that I need to solve. Basically, there are some securities that for their effective term if the value is between 0 to 2  it has score 1, if the value is between 2 to 10, it has score 2, and if the value is bigger than 10 it has value 4.

For the first two conditions, in the query's where part I solve them like this

however for the third condition if the Descriptsec is empty I'm not quite sure what can I do, can anyone help?

Comment: You should not post screenshots to give us code and data. Post the actual text and some DML. Also, your screenshots might reveal potentially sensitive user or company information. I have submitted an edit to remove them, but you should remove them ASAP.

Comment: You can check for empty value and set to either `NULL` or some significant integer value using a CASE statement.

Comment: You should read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3043

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the lookup table ([Risk].[dbo].[FILiquidityBuckets]) you are using?

If yes, do this:

Add bounds so that table looks like this:

```
Metric-DescriptLowerBound-DescriptUpperBound-LiquidityScore
Effective term-0-2-1
Effective term-2-10-2
Effective term-10-9999999(some absurd high number)-4
```

Then your join condition can be this:

```
 ON FB3.Metric='Effective term' 
    AND CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) BETWEEN CAST(FB3.DescriptLowerBound AS INT) 
          AND CAST(FB3.DescriptLowerBound AS INT)
```

Please note that BETWEEN is inclusive so in the edge cases (where the value is exactly 2 or 10), the lower score will be captured.

I can see some problems: the effective term in table with sa alias is a float. So you should consider rounding up or down.

Overall a lot of things can be changed/improved but I tried to offer an immediate solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this is exactly what I did. My problem is still  that I can't include the case when  effective Term is bigger than 10

Comment: You did not do this.

Take a test case: first row where effectiveTerm is 19.273...

In your current logic it is returning NULL because you are not capturing this record with any condition. You have an empty string in DescriptSec. Replace that string with a really high number and it will work. 

I was just pointing at the bad design of the lookup table and the join condition.